# Algorithm with very unlike branch

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, scientific-computing

I'm studying parallel programming and rewriting loops into predicate form. For my research I need some kind of loop with else branch whose probability tends to zero.

It can be any common programming task. But it should be up-to-date and a bit problematic. Any algorithm in any applying field related to computer science and not related.

It can constain multiple level if-else.

Example:

```
if cond
{
    highly possible;
}
else
{
    almost impossible;
    but unavoidable;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for real world existing code, which is probably event-driven and therefor hardly portable? Or are you asking for something portable? That I think is very unlikely the kind of code you are looking for. Please explain about what kind of code you want. Maybe give examples. Why aren't you satisfied with using low-probability rand()? Why are you not using prime factor analysis with side conditions? E.g. looking for numbers with prime factors of a power of at least 10, like 3072=2toThe10*3.

Comment: For example, in hash function every time we add an element we need to check out isn't the table size already achived and therefore we need to increase it. This checking has low and low probability when the size rises.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to talk about "probability" with respect to non-randomized algorithms, where time complexity is generally given with respect to the worst case. The example that immediately comes to my mind, though, is Knuth's "Algorithm D", which performs multi-word division. It contains a conditional correction step which executes, for randomly-chosen n-bit words, with probability on the order of `2^-n`. When testing the algorithm, you really need to specifically formulate a case that'll exercise that conditional, because otherwise you'll never see it run.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that comes to mind is the generation of UUIDs, and using them as identifiers, e.g., in a database. After generating the UUID, you would (theoretically) have to check whether there is a collision with some previously generated UUID, but the probability of a collision is astronomically small.

Comment: As far as I understand definition and purpose of UUIDs, they do span contexts with multiple sources, which cannot synchronise. I.e. it is impossible to verify uniqueness. Could quote something to support that uniqueness check is (theoretically) required? The earlier definitions of the standard did try to achieve uniqueness, but later revisions went completely to random generation.